# How to make custom ListView to open other activities when clicking list item?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to open another activity when clicking the list item. I have created a list view with icon, title, and description. I want to be able to open another activity when i click each list item. I dont know where to put the code. I think it should be a switch statement that opens each position with intents.

Any ideas on how to make that happen ???  Thank you in advance!

here is my MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {





public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {

    // put a switch statement if you want start different activities for each corresponding list item

    //Start other activities
    switch(position){
    case 0:
    Intent toActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EuropaUnion.class);
    startActivity(toActivity);
    break;
    case 1:
        Intent toActivity2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EspaniaClass.class);
        startActivity(toActivity2);
        break;
        default:
            break;

    }
}

private List<Countries> myCountries = new ArrayList<Countries>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    populateCountryList();
    populateListView();
}


private void populateCountryList() {

    myCountries.add(new Countries("European Union", 2014, R.drawable.union_europea, "Europe"));
    myCountries.add(new Countries("Spain", 2015, R.drawable.espania, "Europe"));
    myCountries.add(new Countries("Finland", 2016, R.drawable.finlandia, "Europe"));
    myCountries.add(new Countries("France ", 2017, R.drawable.francia, "Europe"));
    myCountries.add(new Countries("Ireland ", 2018, R.drawable.irlanda, "Europe"));
    myCountries.add(new Countries("Italy", 2014, R.drawable.italia, "Europe"));
    myCountries.add(new Countries("Monaco ", 2014, R.drawable.monaco, "Europe"));
    myCountries.add(new Countries("Portugal", 2014, R.drawable.portugal, "Europe"));
    myCountries.add(new Countries("Russia", 2014, R.drawable.rusia, "Europe"));
    myCountries.add(new Countries("Malta", 2014, R.drawable.malta, "Europe"));


}


private void populateListView() {
    ArrayAdapter<Countries>  adapter = new MyListAdapter();
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.countryList);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}




private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Countries>{
    public MyListAdapter(){
        super(MainActivity.this, R.layout.item_view, myCountries);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View itemView = convertView;
        // make sure we have a view to work with
        if(itemView == null){
            itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_view, parent, false);
        }


        // find country

        Countries currentCountry = myCountries.get(position);

        // fill the view
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_icon);
        imageView.setImageResource(currentCountry.getIconID());

        TextView countryText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.countryName);
        countryText.setText(currentCountry.getCountry());

        TextView yearText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.year);
        yearText.setText("" + currentCountry.getYear());

        TextView continentText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.continent);
        continentText.setText(currentCountry.getContinent());           

        return itemView;

    }



}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Set an `OnItemClickListener` to your `ListView`.

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "You've clicked item nr. " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // start an activity depending on the item/position etc.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way would be to add an OnClickListener to the itemView itself:

```
// this code goes inside your getView() method
itemView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, YourActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});

return itemView;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public class CurrentClass extends Activity {
            .
            .
            .
            .
            .

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                // put a switch statement if you want start different activities for each corresponding list item

                //Start other activities
                Intent toActivity = new Intent(CurrentClass.this,
                        ToNewActivity.class)
                startActivity(toActivity);
            }


                // If you would like to pass some data along to the new activity..... 'SomePojoClass' must implement Serializable

                //Seek and store Data Object
                SomePojoClass somePojoClass = (SomePojoClass) listView
                        .getItemAtPosition(position);


                // you can also pass some object data or just a string data by using 'putExtra', just like a key-value pair
                Intent toActivity = new Intent(CurrentClass.this,
                        ToNewActivity.class).putExtra("passingObjectData",
                        somePojoClass);
                startActivity(toActivity);
            }

            .
            .
            .
            .
            .
}
```

Comment: Do i put this code under  public class currentclass extends activity??

Comment: Not sure what's your question is? but Yes! public void onItemClick should be under your currentClass where you call your list view xml.

Comment: if you look at my question i edited it. i put the switch statement please look. thank you

Comment: paste your LogCat!! please...
alternatively I followed this tutorial... Have a look..
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-listview-with-adapter-example.html

Comment: It shows you how to Toast i dont want to toast I want each list item to open another activity i want a list menu with icon and title

Comment: Nobody here will spoon feed you with the code. If you WANT to do something, then you'd WANT to learn. 

First, Learn how to make a simple listView from the link I shared then,
Improvise the code I've shared(replacing the Toast command) or help yourself here - http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Answer (score 2):

```
enter code herepublic void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
switch(position){
    case 0:
        Intent firstIntent = new Intent(this, MyClass.class);
        startActivity(firstIntentIntent);
        break;  
    case 1:
        Intent secondIntent = new Intent(this, MySecondClass.class);
        startActivity(secondIntentIntent);
                break;

        [... etc ...]
```

}

Comment: i am using this way for onitemclick in listview.

Answer (score 0):

```
   listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

           Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, YourActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```