# how to add action bar items to second activity

Tags: android, android-actionbar

This is my project ([How can i start a different activity on item click from a custom listview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26842916/how-can-i-start-a-different-activity-on-item-click-from-a-custom-listview))
i was able to sort it out.
However when i try to add action bar items like search to the second activity,the items are not being displayed.I know its a simple procedure but i am stuck.I followed the developer's guide (https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html) but to no success.
Any help will be appreciated guys.

Here's the **`second activity code`**:

```
public class School extends ActionbarActivity{
  @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.school);


        Intent newActivity1=new Intent();
        setResult(RESULT_OK, newActivity1);
        //finish();
    }

}
```

**main_activity_actions.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
   <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to extend your activity to ActionBarActivity:

```
public class School extends ActionBarActivity
```

edit:I've tested this code and it's working for me:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
       <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
              android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
              android:title="@string/action_search"
              app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    </menu>
```

Comment: i did,check my edit.That still doesnt solve my issue.

Comment: Post your main_activity_actions.xml, maybe the issue it's there.
Be sure that you have this on "always"
app:showAsAction="always"

Comment: after placing it as "always" the search item is placed in the overflow menu

Comment: Yes it is correct.Its working!Although i had to add <xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">> to use that namespace (app) as the attribute prefix.

Comment: ActionBarActivity is depricated.

Answer (score 1):

There is another option for `Action Bar`.
that is `toolbar`.

The  code for it:

```
//First define toolbar
Toolbar toolbar;

//Then find it by id
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

//then we can add list of menu options in menu.xml
by adding items
```