# How to open new activity after clicking list view with search bar element?

Tags: java, android

**I developed one list view with search bar,so i want to open new activity after clicking on specific search item.**

Comment: please edit your question and read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: did you try `@Override public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) { }`  ?!?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i start a different activity on item click from a custom listview?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26842916/how-can-i-start-a-different-activity-on-item-click-from-a-custom-listview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search on a `listview` and you can use `OnItemClickListener`

From search view

```
new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {
        mListView.clearTextFilter();
    } else {
        mListView.setFilterText(newText.toString()); //you can use this to filter items
    }
    return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And in Listview

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //put some intent 
            }
        }
```

For going to new Activity use this

```
Intent intent=new Intent(getBaseContext(),TargetActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

refer

1. http://www.coderzheaven.com/2013/06/01/create-searchview-filter-mode-listview-android/
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5714068/5962715

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter class you have search bar. On that you can use search bar and transfer to another activity

```
searchView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```